# PHP Create Folder (mkdir) auto add number at Folder name?

Tags: php

```
<?php
   mkdir("testing", 0700);
?>
```

I use this code can create the "testing" folder, but I hope that when I run this code to create folder each time ,it can auto add number at Folder name at first. such as

```
"1testing, 2testing, 3testing, 4testing.........."
```

how to do it???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this code will be helpful to you.

At first go might this solutions seems inefficient but it will work for sure without having database involvement.

**Note:** It will keep on checking for folder names till a specific name is available

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$counter=1;
$path="/path/to/folder/test";
while(is_dir($path))
{
    $path="/path/to/folder/{$counter}test";
    $counter++;
}
mkdir($path);
```

This will create directory only when you have appropriate permissions, else it will end with.

> **Warning:** mkdir(): Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is by storing a last folder no in a database table and then get that value and use it like this mkdir(i+"testing");

Answer (score 0):

```
$path_to_root_folder = "/";
$tmp_list = preg_filter('/^/', $path_to_root_folder, array_diff(scandir($path_to_root_folder), array('..', '.')));

$highest = 0;
$folder_string = "testing";
foreach($tmp_list as $is_folder){
    if(is_dir($is_folder)){
        if(preg_match("#(\d+)testing#", $is_folder, $matched) && $matched[1] > $highest)
            $highest = $matched[1];
    }
}
mkdir($path_to_root_folder.($highest+1).$folder_string);
```

This will also work if there are other folders than your testing folders in the directory.